# En qué archivo se hace la validación para un login?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, cshtml

Estoy revisando un proyecto en ASP.net, este sistema tiene un login, el login esta estructurado algo diferente, esto es parte del código.

```
    <div class="panel-body">
         @using (Html.BeginForm("ToAccess", "LogIn", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off"}))
         {
           inmputs para el usuario, contraseña y el botón.        
         }
    </div>
```

**Saben la ruta del archivo en donde se hacen las validaciones para el login?** Ya intenté buscar la palabra **ToAccess** y **LogIn** pero me salen muchísimos resultados.
No he manejado mucho este lenguaje, pero imagino que ToAccess y LogIn son los argumentos para la funcion BeginForm

Comment: BeginForm es un helper que en sus dos primeros parametros en string recibe el action y el controller,  si las validaciones no son generadas por medio de javascript te recomiendo vayas a ese controlador y ese metodo, para ver si se encuentran en una clase.

Comment: Se puede validar desde el modelo, es decir, desde la clase que corresponde al formulario.

Comment: Busca el archivo LogInController.cs (carpeta controllers) y dentro la función ToAccess

Comment: Gracias Yussef, ya lo encontré. Otra pregunta, sabes donde pueden estar las configuraciones de la conexión a la base de datos? 

Necesito encontrar la base de datos y la tabla donde están los usuarios

Comment: Abraham en appsettings.json. Otra cosa, debes poner una @ antes del nombre para comunicarte por esta plataforma, así llega una alerta al usuario. De pura suerte vi tu mensaje (y creo que bastante tarde)